# How to recursively store BST's node's data into a global array without tracking the global index

Tags: c

So I have a binary search tree that where each node has a single char. There's also a global char array.

How do I recursively go down a tree using let's say a Preorder method (Root, Left, Right) and store each char in the global array in the order that I am traversing the tree?

I cannot create a global index variable, but the function that's traversing and storing the chars returns an int. That int could be used to store the data at a certain index of the g_array.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the index into the recursive search function as a pointer.  Increment it's value as you go along.

```
char g_array[N]; // or 'char* g_array;' with an allocation done elsewhere

void PreorderSearch(struct Node* tree, int *n)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    // visit
    g_array[*n] = tree->value;
    *n = *n + 1;

    PreorderSearch(tree->left, n);
    PreorderSearch(tree->right, n);
}
```

Then invoke with the tree root as follows:

```
void PreoderSearchofTree(struct Node* tree)
{
    int n = 0;
    PreorderSearch(root, &n);
}
```

When PreoderSearch returns, `n` holds the number of elements appended to the array.